# Clickhandler to delete an tablerow

Tags: xamarin.android, android-tablelayout

I'm building an app were i add tablerows to a view programmatically. I add a deletebutton to every row that is an ImageButton. Now i have a few questions.

1. Can i use an ImageButton for this?
2. How do i get the tablerow id
   where the deletebutton was clicked?
3. How can i convert the eventargs
   from a clickhandler into MenuItemOnMenuItemClickEventArgs or vice
   versa?
4. How should my clickhandler look like?

Here is my sourcecode:

```
public class CalculatorSide2 : Activity
{
    private Button stepButton;
    private IntentHelper intentHelper = new IntentHelper();
    private string age;
    private string estLife;
    private string estPens;
    private string[] pensions;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        intentHelper.IntentSide2(Intent, out age, out estLife,out estPens);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.calculatorside2);

        TableLayout tl_layout = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tableLayout1);

        ImageView plusButton = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.plusButton);
        stepButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cside2stepButton);

        plusButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, plusButton);
            popupMenu.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popupmenu);
            fillPopupMenu(popupMenu);
            popupMenu.Show();

            popupMenu.MenuItemClick += (s1, arg) =>
            {
                string info = arg.Item.TitleFormatted.ToString();
                string id = arg.Item.ItemId.ToString();

                var inputDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                EditText userInput = new EditText(this);
                userInput.InputType = (Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber);
                inputDialog.SetTitle(info);
                inputDialog.SetView(userInput);

                inputDialog.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (ss, ee) =>
                {
                    TextView rowInfo = new TextView(this);
                    rowInfo.SetLines(2);
                    rowInfo.TextSize = 20;
                    rowInfo.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
                    rowInfo.Text = info + ": \n" + userInput.Text + "€";

                    ImageButton delete = new ImageButton(this);
                    delete.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.delete_icon));

                    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                    row.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                    row.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(255, 153, 0));
                    row.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 30);

                    row.AddView(rowInfo);
                    row.AddView(delete);
                    tl_layout.AddView(row);
                });
                inputDialog.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (se, es) => { });

                inputDialog.Show();
            };
        };

        stepButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            var step = new Intent(this, typeof(CalculatorSide3));
            step.PutExtra("Age", age);
            step.PutExtra("EstPens", estPens);
            step.PutExtra("EstLife", estLife);
            step.PutStringArrayListExtra("Pensions", pensions);
            StartActivity(step);
        };
    }


    private void fillPopupMenu(PopupMenu menu)
    {
        int groupId = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int menuItemId = Android.Views.Menu.First;
        int menuItemOrder = Android.Views.Menu.None;

        foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(PopupMenuItems)))
        {
            string itemString = item.ToString();
            menu.Menu.Add(groupId, menuItemId + i, menuItemOrder + i, itemString.Replace("_", " "));
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone understands what i mean, bc english is not my native language.

Comment: What is the rationale behind using a TableView? What do you put in it?

Comment: What would you prefer? I want to show some Userinput.

Comment: I would prefer something that uses the Adapter pattern in Android. So for instance a ListView. This will make your life a lot easier when having to remove and add new rows.

Comment: Whatever TableView does ListView does 1000 times better. This is due to the nature that it uses an Adapter, hence it conserves your device memory and allows you to easily populate it with arbitrary data. TableViews have even been left out of the UI documentation for Android because they plain suck! Do whatever you want, but you are going to live with the headache :) If you found a solution, do answer your own question and mark it as answered.

Comment: First i tried it with a ListView but it didn't suit my needs, so i moved to a TableView. But now i got it working. I can post the source code if you wan't.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Sorry if i'm annoying to you, but since i failed to do this with listView i wan't to ask for you help. The thing i wasn't able to do with ListView was the Header, where i have a TextView and the ImageButton for my PopUpMenu. I was able to render them in the View, but when i added an Item it was always in the Header. Unfortunately i can't post pictures yet :( Could you help me to achive this in a ListView please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CalculatorSide2 : Activity
{
    private Button stepButton;
    private IntentHelper intentHelper = new IntentHelper();
    private string age;
    private string estLife;
    private string estPens;
    private string[] pensions;
    private Dictionary<int,string> temp;
    private TableLayout tl_layout;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        intentHelper.IntentSide2(Intent, out age, out estLife,out estPens);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.calculatorside2);

        tl_layout = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tableLayout1);

        ImageView plusButton = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.plusButton);
        stepButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cside2stepButton);

        temp = new Dictionary<int,string>();
        int i = 0;

        plusButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, plusButton);
            popupMenu.Inflate(Resource.Menu.popupmenu);
            fillPopupMenu(popupMenu);
            popupMenu.Show();

            popupMenu.MenuItemClick += (s1, arg) =>
            {
                string info = arg.Item.TitleFormatted.ToString();
                string id = arg.Item.ItemId.ToString();

                var inputDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                EditText userInput = new EditText(this);
                userInput.InputType = (Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber);
                inputDialog.SetTitle(info);
                inputDialog.SetView(userInput);

                inputDialog.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (ss, ee) =>
                {
                    TextView rowInfo = new TextView(this);
                    rowInfo.SetLines(2);
                    rowInfo.TextSize = 20;
                    rowInfo.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
                    rowInfo.Text = info + ": \n" + userInput.Text + "€";

                    ImageButton delete = new ImageButton(this);
                    delete.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.delete_icon));
                    delete.Focusable = false;
                    delete.Clickable = false;

                    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                    row.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                    row.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(255, 153, 0));
                    row.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 30);
                    row.Id = 10 + i;

                    row.Click += new EventHandler(HandleClick);

                    row.AddView(rowInfo);
                    row.AddView(delete);
                    tl_layout.AddView(row);

                    temp.Add(row.Id,userInput.Text);

                    i++;
                });
                inputDialog.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (se, es) => { });

                inputDialog.Show();
            };
        };

        stepButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (temp.Count != 0)
            {
                pensions = new string[temp.Count];
                var j = 0;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in temp)
                {
                    pensions[j] = pair.Value;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                pensions = new string[0];
            }

            var step = new Intent(this, typeof(CalculatorSide3));
            step.PutExtra("Age", age);
            step.PutExtra("EstPens", estPens);
            step.PutExtra("EstLife", estLife);
            step.PutStringArrayListExtra("Pensions", pensions);
            StartActivity(step);
        };
    }

    private void fillPopupMenu(PopupMenu menu)
    {
        int groupId = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int menuItemId = Android.Views.Menu.First;
        int menuItemOrder = Android.Views.Menu.None;

        foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(PopupMenuItems)))
        {
            string itemString = item.ToString();
            menu.Menu.Add(groupId, menuItemId + i, menuItemOrder + i, itemString.Replace("_", " "));
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedTR = sender as TableRow;
        int trId = clickedTR.Id;

        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.SetTitle("Löschen");
        builder.SetMessage("Möchten Sie den Eintrag wirklich löschen?");
        builder.SetPositiveButton("Ja", (ssr,args) => {
            temp.Remove(trId);
            tl_layout.RemoveView(clickedTR);
        });
        builder.SetNegativeButton("Nein",(sse,arge) => { });
        builder.SetCancelable(false);
        builder.Show();
    }
}
```